# How to completely wrap a div around the child div to avoid overflow?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner and I was playing around with css (code given below)
and I set the yellow div to a 1000px and I thought the blue div would automatically
wrap around it given `height:100%;`
but to my surprise the yellow div seemed to overflow, I tried using the `overflow:auto;` but it added a scroll bar to prevent the overflow (which is not what I needed)
so is there anyway that the parent blue div always completely wraps around the yellow div no matter if i set it to a 1000px or 100% height using only CSS?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;

}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#rest {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}


#content {
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  background: yellow;
  height: 1000px;
  position: absolute;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="rest">
      <div id="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#rest {
  min-height: 100%; /* update here */
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

#content {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto; /* remove absolute and center with margin */
  background: yellow;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="rest">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! but I'm having trouble understanding why?
according to https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp shouldn't the min height apply only when the content is smaller than parent?

Comment: @lemonface yes and when bigger the min-height will have no effect and this is what you need. If the content is smaller your div will be 100%, if the content is bigger, you div will follow the content height